# Android build falhou com eas

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, expo

quando eu executo o comando `eas build --platform android` eu vejo esse erro:

> ✖ Build failed
>
> Android build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See
> logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information."

e quando executo  `expo doctor` tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> Expected package @expo/config-plugins@^5.0.0 Found invalid:
> @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5   (for more info, run: npm why
> @expo/config-plugins)

e não sei como atualizar esse `@expo/config-plugins`

Meu arquivo de configuração Eas

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.2.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://baobabrasil.com.br/apiBaoba"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "node": "16.13.0",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "https://baobabrasil.com.br/apiBaoba"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

é um projeto que estou criando gratuitamente para colocar no meu portifólio
meu repositório https://github.com/weslley281/baobabrasil.git

Answer (score -1):

Eu enfrentei o mesmo problema e acabei achando essa [thread aqui](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18401).

Esse problema é bem confuso e pode ser causado por diferentes motivos, na thread o pessoal passa exemplos de soluções que funcionaram para eles, acho que seria interessante dar uma lida e ir na tentativa e erro.

O meu caso foi mais específico, eu utilizo um pacote que é dependente de uma versão específica mais antiga do expo/config-plugins, então entrei no `package-lock.json` e mudei para uma versão mais atual que é compatível.

No seu caso, você pode ver qual pacote está pedindo uma versão mais antiga e atualizá-lo:

1. Abra seu terminal ou cmd na root do projeto
2. Digite `npm ls @expo/config-plugins`
   (Esse comando vai te mostrar todos os caminhos para as versões instaladas desse pacote e o nome dos pacotes que dependem dele, juntamente de sua versão)

Por exemplo: no meu terminal ele mostra os pacotes assim:

```
├── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2
├─┬ azure-ad-graph-expo@2.1.0
│ └─┬ expo-auth-session@1.5.1
│   └─┬ expo-constants@9.3.5
│     └─┬ @expo/config@3.3.43
│       └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
├─┬ expo-constants@14.2.1
│ └─┬ @expo/config@8.0.2
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
├─┬ expo-splash-screen@0.18.2
│ └─┬ @expo/prebuild-config@6.0.1
│   └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
├─┬ expo-updates@0.16.4
│ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
└─┬ expo@48.0.19
  ├─┬ @expo/cli@0.7.3
  │ └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
  └── @expo/config-plugins@6.0.2 deduped
```

(Agora eles estão todos rodando a mesma versão)

3. Encontre o pacote que pede a versão diferente no `package-lock.json` e substitua a versão dependente pela versão que o expo-doctor pede

Se isso não funcionar, você pode tentar:

-Adicionar `"overrides"` (se estiver usando `npm`) ou `"resolutions"` (se estiver usando `yarn`) no seu `package.json` com a versão necessária e depois rodar `expo install`:

```
"overrides": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.0",
  }
```

-Rodar `npm update` no terminal, apagar a `node_modules` e depois rodar npm install novamente;

-Rodar `expo update` no terminal;

-Rodar `npm i -g expo-cli` seguido de `npm update`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Quanto ao problema do **Gradle**, também estou tendo o mesmo erro e tentando resolver. Caso eu encontre a solução, vou voltar aqui para comentar.

Answer (score -2):

Cara já tentou rodar o expo update?

npx expo install expo-updates ou expo install expo-updates
e depois rodar o eas build --platform android
assim como na documentacao
[1]: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).